# I didn't understand this recurrence relation solution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Recently, i was trying to solve this recurrence relation
$$ a_{n+4} = \frac{-\alpha(x)}{(n+4)} \cdot a_{n+3} +\frac{-\beta(x)}{(n+3)\cdot (n+4)} \cdot a_{n+2} $$

But i can't solve for $a_n$

I've tried to solve using Wolfram|Alpha and i got this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n%2B4)%3D-alpha%2F(n%2B4)*a(n%2B3)%20-beta%2F((n%2B3)*(n%2B4))*a(n%2B2)).

How do i get this result and how to solve it.

Edit: n = 0,1,2,3....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** Multiplying by $(n+4)!$ you get 
$$(n+4)!a_{n+4} = -\alpha(x) *(n+3)! a_{n+3} -\beta(x) *(n+2)!a_{n+2}$$

Let $b_n=n! a_n$ then, your recurrence is 
$$b_{n+4}= -\alpha(x) \cdot b_{n+3} -\beta(x) \cdot b_{n+2}$$
which is a standard second order recurrence.

Solve it, and then 
$$a_n=\frac{b_n}{n!}$$

Comment: when i solve this with wolfram|alpha for b result is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b(n%2B4)+%3D+%E2%88%92%CE%B1+*+b(n%2B3)+%E2%88%92+%CE%B2*+b(n%2B2)). This result is very different from the solution above is there something else i'm missing

Comment: @MuratGüven WA solves the second order recurrence, the solution is given by the roots of the characteristic equation (which is what WA has in bracket, under the extra assumption that they are different).

Comment: why beta is in the denominator [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n%2B4)%3D-alpha%2F(n%2B4)*a(n%2B3)+-beta%2F((n%2B3)*(n%2B4))*a(n%2B2))?

Comment: @MuratGüven That is irrelevant... $\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta}}{\beta}c_1$ is just a  contant, so writing that or $C_1$ is the same thing...That particular form probably appears because of the way in which WA solves the recurrence, but most of those constants can be put inside $C_1,C_2$.